# find a sum 'k' using the elements of an array

Tags: c++

i am a newbie to c++. i am trying to find a sum 'k' in an array of numbers. i am using recursion to find if 'k' can be possible using any nos. in the array .I have written the following code.

```
#include<iostream>
using namespace std;

bool isSum(int arr[],int low,int size, int k)
{
    if(k == 0)
        return true;

    if(size == 0)
        return false;


    #using recursion , one recursion including the present no. in the array, another excluding the present no.
    return (isSum(arr,low +1, size-1,k-arr[low]) || isSum(arr, low + 1, size -1 ,k));
}

int main()
{
    int arr[] = {261, 823, 126, 57, 826, 57, 47, 716, 146, 439, 15, 34, 238, 10, 690, 213, 292, 10, 16, 711};;
    bool a = isSum(arr,0,20, 512);
    if(a)
        cout<<"true"<<endl;
    else
        cout<<"false"<<endl;
    }
```

But the above code is giving me true instead of false.what's the problem. thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

In your `return` for `isSum` you want to use the logical and operator `&&` not the logical or operator `||`.  You'll also need a `return` for a single element.

Comment: can you please elaborate, why i have to use && operator. i think if any of the statement is true, then that means that i have found the sum. i just want to know if sum is possible or not.

Comment: also i don't understand what "return for a single element means".